Problem with android sdk licences in flutter. CMDLINE and SDKMANAGER
I'm at Ubuntu 23 and trying to install flutter and initialize to get start development with him; but i have a problem and can't solve it after many hours.
i trying to accept android sdk licenses on flutter but flutter says:
Error: Could not find or load main class SDK.cmdline-tools.latest Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SDK.cmdline-tools.latest Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run (/home/the-mehrdad/Development/Android SDK/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager): "exited code 1". Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK, visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions.
i deleted sdk and installed again with android studio but not work. i'm android developer and now migrating to flutter, this SDK working for me at android develop with java.
can anybody help me please?
i tried many ways. changed my android sdk files and flutter and more ways at internet and AI.

are you able to open android studio and is it working ? also what is the output of command "flutter doctor -v"
